# How does one find their DUID for IPv6 on MacOS?

Tags: network, ipv6

I recently was setting up IPv6 on my home network and while setting up several nodes noticed that the DHCPv6 server was using these DUID strings to identify clients as it assigned IPv6 IPs to the various hosts.

**NOTE:** DUID is the following:

> The DHCP unique identifier (DUID) is used by a client to get an IP address from a DHCPv6 server. It has a 2-byte DUID type field, and a variable-length identifier field up to 128 bytes. Its actual length depends on its type. The server compares the DUID with its database and delivers configuration data (address, lease times, DNS servers, etc.) to the client.

Where can I find this on the client side via the CLI on MacOS?

#### References

- [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol version 6 (DHCPv6) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to piece together a method in which to do this as follows:

```
$ sudo plutil -p /var/db/dhcpclient/DUID_IA.plist
{
  "DUID" => {length = 14, bytes = 0x0001000329b7b1a13c34ec012345}
  "HostUUID" => {length = 16, bytes = 0xf0d23e34de101f1f1be1b4441b412f34}
}
```

So on this particular system it's that 28 character string `0001000329b7b1a13c34ec012345` which is typically represented like this `00:01:00:03:29:b7:b1:a1:3c:34:ec:01:23:45`.

And to extract it with a one-liner:

```
$ sudo plutil -p /var/db/dhcpclient/DUID_IA.plist \
   | awk '/DUID/ {print $8}' \
   | sed -e 's/0x//; s/}//; s/.\{2\}/&:/g; s/:$//'
00:01:00:03:29:b7:b1:a1:3c:34:ec:01:23:45
```

#### References

- [Finding the DHCPv6 DUID on MacOS X 10.11.6](https://csperkins.org/research/misc/2016-09-04-ipv6-duid-macos/)
- [How do I create a Static IPv6 address](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/133174/how-do-i-create-a-static-ipv6-address/8)
- [List DHCP leases held from client](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5579/list-dhcp-leases-held-from-client)